# Calculating $1\sigma$ in each direction from samples of a joint distribution

Tags: covariance

I have values X and Y that I have sampled 10,000 times from a joint distribution. I want to investigate when

- X is low and Y is low
- X is low and Y is mean
- X is low and Y is high
- X is mean and Y is low
- X is mean and Y is mean
- X is mean and Y is high
- X is high and Y is low
- X is high and Y is mean
- X is high and Y is high

The easy way to do this is to look at, for example in the first case, mean(X)-sd(X) and mean(Y)-sd(Y). However, this ignores the covariance of X and Y. How can I take the covariance into account when I am looking at these cases? I can easily calculate the covariance matrix of X and Y, I just do not know how to use the information.

Comment: You can use Mahalanobis distance for this. If you consider the set of all points with a fixed mahalanobis distance from the centroid and traverse along this isocontour, you will encounter the points that satisfy the different properties that you list.

Comment: Regression of $X$ on $Y$ and $Y$ on $X$ answers these questions *by design*.

Comment: @whuber can you say a bit more about how to do this please? To give an R-specific example, I can make `X.lm<-lm(X~Y)` and `Y.lm<-lm(Y~X)` and then use for example `predict` on each of them, but how do I do for example the case when X is low and Y is high? I can put `mean(X)-sd(X)` into the `Y.lm` but then I (obviously) get out a quite different Y than `mean(Y)+sd(Y)`. How should I do it in practice?

Comment: I figured it out by first decorrelating the variables using PCA, then using the Mahalanobis distance to calculate an oval whose diameters are $1\sigma$, then picking out the points that I want on that oval and projecting them back into the original space